# Previous - Next week on angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to implement a previous - next week stats which will change the url depending on  StartDate and EndDate values of a datepicker but will show stats of a week (like from 11-11-13 18-11-13 and so on).
Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: And the problem is ...?

Comment: I'm just asking for suggestions and ideas on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in case someone stubles on it looking for an answer, here is one.

I do not know your code structure, so I will assume you have a controller with a structure/method like this:

```
// this is tied to your HTML with ng-model (I assume)
this.currentDate = new Date();

// tie this to your "next week" button with ng-click
this.iterateDate = function() {

    var nextWeek = new Date(this.currentDate.valueOf());

    // adding/subtracting 7 for next/previous week. Can be less for your use case
    nextWeek.setDate(nextWeek.getDate() + 7);

    // update the model value (if this is your approach)
    this.currentDate = nextWeek;
};
```

Again, without knowing how you structured your controller it is hard to give an exact implementation. The `iterateDate` function should do what you ask for though.

Credit to [@AnthonyWJones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date) for his date change function.